# CSV Reader duplicate issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

**TL;DR: Can you not *reliably* iterate through a csv object itself, or use an (if/not in) against it?**

So I am having a strange issue. It appears to be intermittent, but that's just because I have no idea what's going on. I'm sure there's an actual cause.

I have the following:

```
import os
import csv


csv_old = 'vendor_old.csv'
csv_new = 'vendor.csv'
csv_sftp = 'vendor_sftp.csv'


def check_vendor_length():
    with open(csv_old, 'r') as t_old:
        vendor_old = csv.reader(t_old, delimiter = ',')

        all_vendor_old = next(vendor_old)
        len_vendor_old = len(all_vendor_old)

        return len_vendor_old


def check_vendor_old():
    with open(csv_old, 'r') as t_old, open(csv_new, 'r') as t_new, open(csv_sftp, 'w', newline = '') as t_sftp:
        vendor_old = csv.reader(t_old, delimiter = ',')
        vendor_new = csv.reader(t_new, delimiter = ',')
        vendor_sftp = csv.writer(t_sftp, delimiter = ',')

        all_vendor_old = []
        row_vendor_old = next(vendor_old)
        row_vendor_old.insert(csv_len, 'action')
        all_vendor_old.append(row_vendor_old)

        for row_vendor_old in vendor_old:
            if row_vendor_old not in vendor_new:
                all_vendor_old.append(row_vendor_old + ['remove'])
        vendor_sftp.writerows(all_vendor_old)


def check_new():
    with open(csv_old, 'r') as t_old, open(csv_new, 'r') as t_new, open(csv_sftp, 'a', newline = '') as t_sftp:
        vendor_old = csv.reader(t_old, delimiter = ',')
        vendor_new = csv.reader(t_new, delimiter = ',')
        vendor_sftp = csv.writer(t_sftp, delimiter = ',')

        all_vendor_new = []
        row_vendor_new = next(vendor_new)
        row_vendor_new.insert(csv_len, 'action')

        for row_vendor_new in vendor_new:
            all_vendor_new.append(row_vendor_new + ['add'])
        vendor_sftp.writerows(all_vendor_new)
```

So, first function compares the old CSV against the new one. If there are rows in the old one that are NOT in the new one, they should be marked for removal. They are WRITTEN to a (new new) CSV that will be SFTP'd to the vendor.

The second function just takes all the data from the new CSV and APPENDS it to the SFTP CSV.

**What was happening was that the SFTP CSV that was generated last night had duplicates of everything, with the only difference being that there were first the 'remove' entries, and then after all of those, the same rows, but with 'add' instead of 'remove'.**

But that didn't always happen. In testing, it worked as expected. No dups. But for some reason, again, last night's SFTP had all the dups. The CSVs that were being processed by this had only about 10 columns, and about 5100 rows.

Strangely, when I pared it down a little so that I was only working with about 2-300 rows, I ran into the same issue.

There's extra code not shown, but basically, after the SFTP CSV is created, the old CSV was deleted, and the new CSV was renamed to the old CSV name. Then, then next day, when the new CSV gets dumped into the directory, the script can run again. Rinse and repeat.

The closest that we could determine was that maybe iterating through the **CSV OBJECT ( vendor_new = csv.reader(t_new, delimiter = ',')** ) was borking the process somehow. So what I've done is modified the check_vendor_old function so that the new CSV gets read into a list first, then the for loop checks for the old CSV row against the new CSV list:

```
def check_vendor_old():
    with open(csv_old, 'r') as t_old, open(csv_new, 'r') as t_new, open(csv_sftp, 'w', newline = '') as t_sftp:
        vendor_old = csv.reader(t_old, delimiter = ',')
        vendor_new = csv.reader(t_new, delimiter = ',')
        vendor_sftp = csv.writer(t_sftp, delimiter = ',')

        all_vendor_old = []
        row_vendor_old = next(vendor_old)
        row_vendor_old.insert(csv_len, 'action')
        all_vendor_old.append(row_vendor_old)


        ################ NEW STUFF HERE ################
        # Create list comprised of new vendor.csv rows
        list_vendor_new = []
        for row in vendor_new:
            list_vendor_new.append(row)
        # print(list_vendor_new)
        ################ NEW STUFF HERE ################


        for row_vendor_old in vendor_old:
            if row_vendor_old not in list_vendor_new:
                all_vendor_old.append(row_vendor_old + ['remove'])
        vendor_sftp.writerows(all_vendor_old)
```

So this all now appears to be working as expected...but I guess we'll see.

So my question is, is there something that I missed when reading the csv reader documentation? Can you not *reliably* iterate through the csv object itself, or use an [if / not in] against it? It seemed to work during testing, but clearly something didn't go as planned last night.

**UPDATE**
I've found that `vendor_new.seek(0)` doesn't work (because the `vendor_new` class is `_csv.reader`, which has no seek method), but `t_new` (what I opened the CSV as) is `_io.TextIOWrapper`, which DOES have the seek method.

So I imagine, if I were to do:

```
def check_vendor_old():
...
    for row_vendor_old in vendor_old:
        if row_vendor_old not in vendor_new:
            all_vendor_old.append(row_vendor_old + ['remove'])
        t_new.seek(0)
```

THIS might be closer to what I want. (If I *really* wanted to work with the csv.reader object instead of a list.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue in the original code is this:

```
def check_vendor_old():
    ...
    for row_vendor_old in vendor_old:
        # !!! - this is not doing what you think its doing ...
        if row_vendor_old not in vendor_new:
            all_vendor_old.append(row_vendor_old + ['remove'])
```

Now, `vendor_new` is not a list ... it is an iterator.  Checking whether something is in the iterator consists of advancing it until a match is found.  The next time you do this check it will begin from where that iterator was left.

To provide an example, consider this iterator:

```
>>> r = (x for x in range(10))
```

Is `5` in it?

```
>>> print(5 in r)
True
```

Of course it is.  But is `3` in it?

```
>>> print(3 in r)
False
```

No ... its not, because when finding the `5` we advanced the iterator up to just beyond the `5`.  If you crystallize your iterator to a list, the problem disappears:

```
>>> r = list(x for x in range(10))
>>> print(5 in r)
True
>>> print(3 in r)
True
```

Comment: Thanks for that. While your response is helpful, can you help clarify something for me? Assuming the `vendor_new` object consists of 5 rows, what is actually happening when I do `if row_vendor_old not in vendor_new`? Is it advancing through `vendor_new` once, and then not resetting on the next `for row_vendor_old in vendor_old` loop? Can/should something like `vendor_new.seek(0)` be used to reset `vendor_new`?

Comment: Its an `iterator`, its not a `file` and its not a `list`, its not any kind of container.  Its just an `iterator`, **all it can do is move forward**.  It can't "reset".  If you need to keep checking things in it, convert it to a proper container (just as you did in the example that worked).

Answer (score 0):

So I decided on doing this:

```
def check_vendor_old():
...
    for row_vendor_old in vendor_old:
        t_new.seek(0) ### Added this here
        if row_vendor_old not in vendor_new:
            all_vendor_old.append(row_vendor_old + ['remove'])
```

Resetting the `t_new` position to 0 at the start of each loop. I thought it didn't work at first because it was taking a long time to run, but it was just because it was iterating 5000 lines in one CSV as well as 5000 lines in another CSV, instead of doing a single pass like how my original bad code was first working.

So, I'm giving the answer **to my post** to @donkopotamus as that response directly answered what I originally asked, and I wouldn't have been able to find *my* answer with their help, but I'd say that this is probably the answer I was looking for.

Comment: This is probably a very inefficient means of doing the problem, if you keep seeking back to the start of the file you will keep doing unnecessary i/o as you re-read and re-read and re-read the file.

Comment: You're right. What I found was that it was definitely taking much longer doing it this way. About 30 seconds, vs near instantaneous with the list. So yes, using seek does seem to be not the best way. Thanks for your help and clarifications.